# Exporting Google Sheets to Firebase ERROR

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get information about bills from this website:

> https://www.congress.gov/search?q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22legislation%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%22115%22%7D

I set up the nodes in firebase already and have a google sheet that automatically updates the information I need. I created a google script that should update firebase from google scripts. It looks like this:

```
function sheetsToFireBase() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1yZ1Kre0nRzYX1hNyeyOo5OfFrVWnOVRoPRH3jje_wCM");
  var sheets = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheets.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = data.getValues();
  var dataToImport = {};
  for(var i = 1; i < dataValues.length; i++) { //set data in .JSON format
    var BillName = dataValues[i][14];
    dataToImport[BillName] = {
      Name:BillName,
      //Billlink:dataValues[i][1],
      Description:dataValues[i][15],
      Representative:dataValues[i][8],
      LatestActions:dataValues[i][11],
    };
  }

  for (var sheetNum=0; sheetNum<sheets.length; sheetNum++) { //test if code ran
    var sheet = sheets[sheetNum];
          sheet.getRange("M2:M101").setValue("Code Ran");
          sheet.getRange("N2:N101").setValue(Math.round(Math.random()*100000));
        }

  var firebaseUrl = "REDACTED FOR SECURITY";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  base.setData("", dataToImport); //export data to firebase
}
```

*note: I commented out the Billlink:dataValues[i][1] because it has "/" in the link and I am not sure if that is causing the error so I disabled it for now.
For some reason I keep getting

> Error: Invalid data; couldn't parse key beginning at 1:34432. Key value can't be empty or contain $ # [ ] / or . (line 272, file "Code", project "FirebaseApp")

Why is this happening? I do not have $ # [ ] / or . in any of the cells I'm exporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the Error Message is showing is that Firebase is reading the formula rather than the result. So, in order to fix this,  the data must be populated with the result of the formula without the formula being present at all. This can be achieved via google scripting: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664000/how-to-automate-moving-data-from-one-google-sheet-to-another) Stack Overflow post.